# Searching for dota 2 game coordinator

Tags: dota-2

Everytime I try to open dota it gives me error message, "searching for dota 2 game coordinator". And after that it says, "Connected to dota 2 Game coordinator; loggin in". But I am not able to do anything in dota.

I tried restarting dota 2 several times and also tried steam restart but nothing is helping here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dota 2 game coordinator is down. There's nothing you can do other than wait.

Comment: Although OP mentions they did this, sometimes a simply restart dota / steam can fix it (or at least gives enough time for the coordinator to come back up) so I see both as options. Once done, there's nothing to do but wait.

Answer (score 2):

In future, you can check the this [unofficial status page](https://steamstat.us/) to see if the problem is on your end or on the server side.

For example, right now it is having server issues and is down.

[image: Dota 2 down]